# Is there a good example of using GDAL_WMS to add an authenticated TMS layer to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, gdal, authentication, tile-map-service

I've been trying to add a TMS layer in QGIS using a GDAL_WMS xml configuration file.

I added UserPwd to the xml and this seems to provide the authentication required by GeoServer but I'm struggling to get it to display correctly and in the correct place.

The map mostly loads as black but occasionally I can find the odd area that displays bits that look a bit like a map however I've yet to get it to load even close to correctly in QGIS.

Does anyone have a specific example of how they successfully added a GeoServer TMS layer using this method?

Example XML

```
<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="TMS">  <ServerUrl>http://wms.domain.com/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/workspace%3Alayername/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>22</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<Cache />
<OfflineMode>false</OfflineMode>
<UserPwd>user:password</UserPwd>
<ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,303,400,404,500,501</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
<ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
```

Comment: Add your xml configuration file to your question. You can use fake WMS server address and username/password.

Comment: I have edited the original post to show an example configuration file